# Реализовать getMapAsync() в классе

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, google-maps

Есть активити в которой реализую метод `getMap()`, но так как он `depricated` я его не могу реализовать в полной мере. Нашёл несколько вариантов решения данной проблемы, одним из них было реализовать вместо него метод `getMapAsync()` после чего имплементировать интерфейс `OnMapReadyCallback`, вместе с ним появляется метод `onMapReady`. Проблема в том, что не знаю что конкретно туда впихнуть (думаю сами маркеры, но они у меня взаимосвязаны в `onCreate`) и самое главное как правильно модифицировать мой класс. Подскажите как быть.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ViewGroup infoWindow;
    private TextView infoTitle;
    private TextView infoSnippet;
    private Button infoButton;
    private OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener infoButtonListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        final MapWrapperLayout mapWrapperLayout = (MapWrapperLayout)findViewById(R.id.map_relative_layout);
        final GoogleMap map = mapFragment.getMap();

        // MapWrapperLayout initialization
        // 39 - default marker height
        // 20 - offset between the default InfoWindow bottom edge and it's content bottom edge
        mapWrapperLayout.init(map, getPixelsFromDp(this, 39 + 20));

        // We want to reuse the info window for all the markers,
        // so let's create only one class member instance
        this.infoWindow = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
        this.infoTitle = (TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.title);
        this.infoSnippet = (TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
        this.infoButton = (Button)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.button);

        // Setting custom OnTouchListener which deals with the pressed state
        // so it shows up
        this.infoButtonListener = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(infoButton,
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_green_sel), //btn_default_normal_holo_light
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_red_sel)){ //btn_default_pressed_holo_light
            @Override
            protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
                // Here we can perform some action triggered after clicking the button
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, marker.getTitle() + "'s button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        this.infoButton.setOnTouchListener(infoButtonListener);


        map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                // Setting up the infoWindow with current's marker info
                infoTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
                infoSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
                infoButtonListener.setMarker(marker);

                // We must call this to set the current marker and infoWindow references
                // to the MapWrapperLayout
                mapWrapperLayout.setMarkerWithInfoWindow(marker, infoWindow);
                return infoWindow;
            }
        });

        // Let's add a couple of markers

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("India")
                .snippet("New Delhi")
                .position(new LatLng(20.59, 78.96)));

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Prague")
                .snippet("Czech Republic")
                .position(new LatLng(50.08, 14.43)));

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Paris")
                .snippet("France")
                .position(new LatLng(48.86,2.33)));

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("London")
                .snippet("United Kingdom")
                .position(new LatLng(51.51,-0.1)));
    }

    public static int getPixelsFromDp(Context context, float dp) {
        final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return (int)(dp * scale + 0.5f);
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чём проблема переноса добавления маркеров в onMapReady?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб получается нужно перенести всё от строчки `        mapWrapperLayout.init(map, getPixelsFromDp(this, 39 + 20));` но тогда опять же получается не совсем корректно.

Comment: Почему не корректно?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб перенёс, но в строчке `        final GoogleMap map = mapFragment.getMapAsync();
` выдаёт ошибку : getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback) in MapFragment cannot be applied to ()

Comment: Ну так передайте туда анонимную реализацию колбэкп

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы реализуете интерфейс OnMapReadyCallback, вам нужно реализовать метод onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap), который будет вызван как только карта будет готова к роботе. Собственно там и можно добавить маркеры.

```
final GoogleMap map = mapFragment.getMapAsync();
```

Ошибку выдает потому, что mapFragment.getMapAsync() возвращает void, а как аргумент должен принять onMapReadyCallback, то есть ваше активити, которое его реализует.

Можете сделать глобальную переменную private GoogleMap mMap, и в методе onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) находите свою карту.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
mMap = googleMap;
//остальной код
}
```

Comment: Где скачать библиотеку что бы в ней был интерфейс OnMapReadyCallback?